# PHP require_once still requires multiple times

Tags: php

My understanding of require_once is that it would prevent multiple PHP files from requiring the same file again. That does not seem to be the case.

**functions.php**

```
function myFunction(){}
```

**middleware.php**

```
require_once("functions.php");
```

**app.php**

```
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("middleware.php");
```

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare myFunction() (previoiusly declared in functions.php....`

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your example code

Comment: Yeah I'm losing my mind. I've never seen this in my life. I've not made any changes to the code. Suddenly this appears. =/

Comment: Can you reproduce it with your example code? =)

Comment: Christ.. I found the problem. I accidentally uploaded functions.php to another folder and .. not really sure how, but some other include picked it up.. wow. I maybe PHP outsmarted itself with file pathing, or... ah. whatever. Delete the file. Problem gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if it is requiring a different functions file.  Are app.php and middleware.php in the same folder or a different folder?

My suggestion is whenever you use `require`, `include`, `include_once`, or `require_once`, that you always use absolute paths using `__DIR__`.

Such as `require_once __DIR__.'/path/to/file.php'`

Comment: Yes it was essentially lacking a proper `__DIR__` or some other form of hardcoded directory. PHP was being too smart and picked up a duplicate of the file that I uploaded to another folder.